# Moving TextField and labels up when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

My problem is trying to fit all of your components on the screen after the keyboard appears using the swift language.

I found this piece of code,but unfortunately this only brings my textView to the top of the screen and does nothing with the other things.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView :UITextView)
{
    var scrollPoint:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, textView.frame.origin.y);
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)

}

func textViewDidEndEditing (textView :UITextView)
{
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zeroPoint, animated: true)

}
```

How should i change this piece of code to keep the button at it's current position and the two labels too.

For now I only want to do this for a button and two labels,how much do have to change when it comes to having a UITable in my view?

Thank you very much

Comment: It basically comes down to setting each components frame.y value up and down by 80 pts.

Comment: sorry for the dmb question but why 80 pts?

Comment: Heya I just meant the height of the keyboard - maybe its more than 80 :)

Comment: After looking at this link am i right to assume it's eight is 216?   http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/keyboard.html

Comment: Why not put all of your things into a view and just adjust the view?

Comment: Ohhhh....I see what you mean....Can I also resize the view?meaning if I have a UITable there can I resize it?and if I can how may I go around doing that?